# Throw exceptions in logically impossible situations?

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, conditional-statements

I wonder if it is a good practice or a waste of code to throw an exception in logically impossible condition.

Example:

```
def __init__(self, type, list_of_variables):
        if type == "var":
            rand_index_var = random.randint(0,len(list_of_variables)) # Since this rand is created from 'list_of_variables'
            if len(list_of_variables) >= rand_index_var: # It is impossible that this condition will fail, at least that a non human error would raise it
                self.symbol = list_of_variables[rand_index_var]
            else:
                raise Exception(f"list index out of range {rand_index_var}")
```

I would probably maintaing the current version, as there might be an exceptionally rare scenario caused by an OS malfunction, hardware issues, or other factors.

Comment: Programs are logically executed, so any code that is logically unreachable is a waste both physically and mentally to those who maintain the code in the future (who have to spend a fraction of their mental capacity to wonder why the code is there at all).

Comment: If the condition must always be true, then why have an `if..else` at all? Should that index ever somehow happen to be outside the list's range, then accessing the offset will raise an exception anyway. So this is all redundant and superfluous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If something is literally impossible, it is a waste of everyone's time to even test for it.  There is no point writing code that can never be executed.  Indeed, it makes more work for other people; e.g. someone reading the test coverage report, someone in the future trying to understand the code.

If the something *should not* happen (but might), then it is a "toss up" whether or not to test for it:

- If the something is likely to cause significant damage if it is occurs, then an explicit test is warranted.
- If it is objectively harmless, or if it would trigger an exception anyway, then an explicit test is redundant.

In your example, if `rand_index_var` was ever out of range, then

```
    list_of_variables[rand_index_var]
```

would raise an exception.  So this falls into the "don't test for it" bucket ... *whether or not it is literally impossible*.

If you really want to, you could add a comment.  I wouldn't bother since it should be obvious to a reader of the code that the scenario is impossible.